# How can I make a transaction go to a random address in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, addresses

I want to write a cryptocurrency that has a feature that sends tokens from the sender to a random receipient address that has made a transaction recently on the blockchain.
How would I start off doing something like this?

Basically in the following, I'd like balances[to] to be a random address, selected from adresses that have been involved recently in transactions

```
function Send(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
         balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(tokens);
         balances[to] = balances[to].add(tokens);
         Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
         return true;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

1. I don't think Solidity has access to a list of recent transactions from which to pick an address. You'd need to use some sort of oracle.
2. Solidity doesn't have a source of true randomness. There are many ways to approximate randomness if the stakes are low (so you don't worry about miner manipulation), or you can use an oracle to provide true random numbers.

What's the trust model here? Is there a reason you can't just send in the address from outside? Does the logic to pick an address really have to reside on-chain?

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'm just beginning to work with solidity.
the idea is that a user can perform a certain action on the contract, but has to accept that his balance is sent to a random address as payment for the service. the random recepient should be someone who is actively using the network to transfer balances. How would I send in the address from outside in this case?

Comment: You could set aside the balance and later call (from off-chain) a method like `send(to, tokens)` where you fill in `to` with a random address from recent transactions.